# optimization problem over finite groups (or at least finitely generated groups)

Tags: group-theory, optimization, finite-groups, discrete-optimization, finitely-generated

Have you ever seen any optimization problem over finite groups (or finitely generated groups)? That is, given a group $G$, we want to maximize or minimize a function $f$ over $G$.

An example that struck my mind, was $N$-queens problem. We can define a function $f$ as number of pairwise conflicts. In this problem, group $G$ is $S_N$.

You know, $(ℤ,+)$ is also a finitely generated group, and any integer programming problem will be the answer. But for this trivial groups, I mean a problem having a group theoretic approach.

I will also be grateful if you can mention the current approaches to solve that optimization problem.

Comment: I don't see how the number of pairwise conflicts changes if you permits the queens. Isn't that function just constant?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No, it's not constant. For instance, if the permutation is identity, all the queens are in a diagonal arrangement so all of them conflict with each other. Therefore $f(id)=n(n-1)/2$. But the goal of N-queens problem is to find an arrangement $π$ that $f(π)=0$

Comment: Ah, so "pairwise" means the pairs $(x,\pi x),$ where $\pi$ is the permutation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No. Let me define f explicitly for the N-queens problem. $f(π)=#{(i,j) s.t. |π(i)-π(j)| = |i-j| }$ which shows the diagonal conflicts. Since permutations don't have row and column conflicts, we don't have to consider them in $f$.

Comment: Unless the function is related to the group structure somehow, why is it relevant that there is a group structure at all?

Comment: @ronno It can defintely have some benefits. For instance there have been many papers on permutation puzzles, including Rubik's cube or 15 puzzle having an algebraic perspective.

Comment: If they are the results I think you're talking about, the function there is precisely the length of an element as a word in certain generators, so of course that interacts with the group structure. Whereas in the $n$-queens problem this is not clear to me, and definitely not for a general function on a general group.